# Arbitrary precision floating types in Julia

Tags: constants, julia

I have a constant value:

```
M_LN2 = 0.693147180559945309417
```

I tried storing it as:

```
M_LN2 = BigFloat(0.693147180559945309417)
```

The result seems to be adding too many extra digits:

> 6.931471805599452862267639829951804131269454956054687500000000000000000000000000e-01

I tried:

```
M_LN2 = Float64(0.693147180559945309417)
```

But it is truncating the value:

> 0.6931471805599453

Could you suggest what would be the correct way to initialize the constant?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you change your title to something containing "arbitrary precision floating types" or "BigFloats"? Then it would be found more easily in the future.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write `BigFloat(0.693147180559945309417)`, Julia constructs a `Float64` value of the literal value `0.69314718055994530941`, which already performs some truncation:

```
julia> 0.69314718055994530941
0.6931471805599453
```

The resulting value is then passed as an argument to the `BigFloat` function. To avoid that, you have to circumvent the parsing of the numeric literal.  The most convenient way for that is the `big` string macro:

```
julia> big"0.693147180559945309417"
6.931471805599453094169999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999979e-01
```

Which internally probably does just `parse(BigFloat, "0.693147180559945309417")` to "manually" parse the value from the given string, without interpretation from Julia in between.

Answer (score 4):

The secret is to enclose your number with quotes ("). So the value is converted directly from String into BigFloat.

```
julia> println("Julia version ",VERSION); 
       M_LN2 = BigFloat("0.693147180559945309417")
Julia version 1.0.0
6.931471805599453094169999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999979e-01
```